# linux terminal Как отвязать приложение от терминала?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, консоль, администрирование

Как в linux отвязать приложение от терминала, чтобы можно было запустить программу и закрыть терминал, а программа продолжила работать?
Сейчас приходится ставить в cron на @reboot и перезагружать сервер, но это не удобно.
Пробовал использовать утилиту screen но она очень неудобная... Хотелось бы найти что-то вроде стандартной jobs, чтобы в bg когда оставляешь он не закрывал программу при закрытии терминала.

Comment: `help disown` или `man nohup`

Comment: `tmux`, `screen`.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можете перевести выполнение программы в фоновый режим с помощью &

Comment: Программа убьётся контролирующим терминалом при закрытии пользовательской сессии, учите матчасть.

Comment: @0andriy, терминал можно закрывать. Выведется номер процесса и появится возможность ввести новую команду. При закрытии терминала процесс продолжит работать.

Comment: @Olegator36, о сколько нам открытий чудных готовят просвещенья друг... вы бы для начала разобрались, что такое «терминал» и что такое «эмулятор терминала», потом перешли к понятию «пользовательской сессии», и уже напоследок к понятию «управляющего терминала».